# How to set HTTPONLY and SECURE security flags in cookies that are automatically generated in Angular

Tags: angular, httponly

when we enter the site in angular, we can observe that some cookies are generated automatically.

Example Cookies ...

rxvt
rxVisitor
dtPC
dtLatC
dtSa
dtCookie

But they start without the httponly and secure security flags

How do I make these cookies have these flags?